# Register beforeCommit callback for all Spring managed transactions

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am using the ChainedTransactionManager to implement Best Effort 1PC across ActiveMQ and MySQL, in my case the Database transaction commits first. In order to reduce the window of failure I want to check whether the ActiveMQConnection has failed just before committing the database transaction. I can do this once a transaction has started with the TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization, but what I want is to register a block of code that runs for every transaction without having to do it in my code.

I could just subclass the ChainedTransactionManager but this does not seem the cleanest. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Looks like subclassing ChainedTransactionManager is not a good idea as it relies on MultiTransactionStatus which is not public. Creating a new PlatformTransactionManager that delegates to a ChainedTransactionManager is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have decided to implement it:

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

public class JmsTransportFailureHandlingTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager {

    private final ChainedTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager;

    public JmsTransportFailureHandlingTransactionManager(ChainedTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager) {
        this.chainedTransactionManager = chainedTransactionManager;
    }


    @Override
    public TransactionStatus getTransaction(TransactionDefinition definition) throws TransactionException {
        TransactionStatus transaction = chainedTransactionManager.getTransaction(definition);

        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void beforeCommit(boolean readOnly) {
                for (Object resource : TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap().values()) {
                    if (resource instanceof JmsResourceHolder) {
                        ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) ((JmsResourceHolder) resource).getConnection();
                        if (connection.isTransportFailed()) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("ActiveMQ transport failed.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return transaction;
    }

    @Override
    public void commit(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        chainedTransactionManager.commit(status);
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        chainedTransactionManager.rollback(status);
    }
}
```